# datatables does not load json (array with objects)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to setup datables with sorced data from ajax. The file outputs an array with objects:

```
[{"column":"content","column":"content"}]
```

But it's not loading the data, it keeps proccessing.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    processing: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    ajax: '/get?op=2',
    language: {
        "url": "//website.com/js/DataTables-Spanish.json"
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'columns' }
        // more columns
    ],
    select: true
});
```

This is the code of the file:

```
if ($op === 2) {

    $result = $functions->get_prop_table_test();

    header('Content-type: text/json');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

The only error I see is in the console:

```
TypeError: f is undefined    datatables.min.js:60:375
ia/<()                       datatables.min.js:60
ra/i()                       datatables.min.js:47
ra/o.success()               datatables.min.js:47
n.Callbacks/j()              jquery.min.js:8
n.Callbacks/k.fireWith()     jquery.min.js:8
x()                          jquery.min.js:10
.send/b/<()                  jquery.min.js:10
```

https://cdn.datatables.net/s/zf/dt-1.10.10,b-1.1.0,se-1.1.0/datatables.min.js

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `dataSrc: ''` as shown below to match your JSON data format, see [`dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) for more information. Use the following initialization options:

```js
ajax: {
   url: '/get?op=2',
   dataSrc: ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically an error like this originates in the data returned. If you're using Spanish language data, it might be the encodings don't match (UTF-8 vs ASCII, etc) and the accents are causing you trouble.

Can you post a sample of the data you're returning from `$functions -> get_prop_table_test();`

Comment: I removed the language option, still not working. The data returned is exactly as the example i put above, an array with an object per row.